# Asus notebook doesn't detect Kingston memory

Tags: memory, asus-laptop

My Asus f550ldv-xx562h notebook doesn't detect my Kingston DDR3-1600 4GB RAM Memory.

Only CPU-Z detects the installed memory.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:
I put in the laptop: Kingston DDR3-1600 4GB RAM Memory How much Windows 8 sees: 4GB (Already installed) and CPU-Z in tab "SPD" sees that the Kingston is inserted in the slot.

so i have now 2 RAMs, 1 already installed on the motherboard, and one in the RAM slot. The BIOS does not see BOTH modules

Comment: Please elaborate. If you run a 32bit operating system you will be limited to about 3.3GB.

Comment: I'm running on Windows 8 64-bit. Max allowed installed ram: 8GB, Currently there is 4GB in it.

Comment: So please elaborate how much memory you put in the laptop, how much windows 8 sees and what do you mean only cpu-z detects it

Comment: I put in the laptop: Kingston DDR3-1600 4GB RAM Memory
How much Windows 8 sees: 4GB (Already installed) and CPU-Z in tab "SPD" sees that the Kingston is inserted in the slot.

Comment: What about bios, does it see both modules?

Comment: Ok let me guess. Your laptop comes with a 4GB RAM and now you have installed a second 4GB RAM which is not detected by your laptop? Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes it is. Asus's website tells that my notebook supports a maximum of 8GB DDR3, so i have now 2 RAMs, 1 already installed on the motherboard, and one in the RAM slot. The BIOS does not see BOTH modules

Comment: @Jordy you should mention all the relevant details in your question. Otherwise it becomes difficult for others to understand what is the problem.

Comment: Edited my question, Excuse me

Comment: Ok can you post the screen shot of CPU-Z's SPD tab for both the RAM slots?

Comment: @AyanPatra Please see [here](http://jordybakker.nl/ramkingston.png) for a screenshot

Comment: @Jordy if you have not updated the BIOS ever since you have been using the laptop, then try updating to latest BIOS of your laptop available at Asus website. There are some who faced similar problem while upgrading the RAM of their Asus Vivobook for a different model though and the solution was a simple BIOS update. You can take a look at the post [here](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1666282/asus-ram-upgrade-recognized.html). See if this solves your problem or not.

Comment: @Ayan Updated the BIOS but still 4GB instead of 8GB :(

Comment: @Jordy I checked your laptop's specification from Asus website. There it is mentioned your laptop supports **DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM** RAM. Now DDR3L runs at a lower voltage 1.35V compared to standard DDR3 which runs at 1.5V. Now since you are using a standard DDR3 RAM (CPU-Z is showing the voltage at 1.5V) in a DDR3L slot the RAM module is not getting sufficient power. That is why it is unusable by the system. You can take a look at this [post](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1859845/ddr3-ddr3l-slots.html) for more details. I think you should change your DDR3 for a DDR3L RAM.

Comment: @Ayan Thank you very much for your help, this solves my problem. I 'll return my DDR3 and get an DDR3L.